# if and elif for three conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am analyzing stock trend though SMA 15 as follow:

1. If closing price value leads its MA15 and MA15 is rising for last 5 days then trend   is Uptrend i.e. trend signal is 1.
2. If closing price value lags its MA15 and MA15 is falling for last 5 days then trend is Downtrend i.e. trend signal is 0.
3. if none of these rules are satisfied then stock market is said to have no trend.

I knoww how to do two conditions the first and the second, but I want to add the third with no trend.

```
## Data loading..
!pip install yfinance
import pandas as pd 
import yfinance as yf

df=yf.download('^GSPC',start='2015-11-26',end='2020-12-31',interval='1d')
# this is how I did it 

df['SMA15']=df['Adj Close'].rolling(15).mean()
df['SMA15-5']=df['SMA15'].rolling(5).mean()
df['SMA15-5dif']=df['SMA15-5'].diff()

df['Trend']=['up' if df.loc[ei,'Close']>df.loc[ei,'SMA15'] and (df.loc[ei,'SMA15-5dif']> 0 ) else 'down' for ei in df.index] ## this gave me up and down but no "no"

# I did this but was wrong 
df['Trend']=['up' if df.loc[ei,'Close']>df.loc[ei,'SMA15'] and (df.loc[ei,'SMA15-5dif']> 0 ) elif df.loc[ei,'Close']<df.loc[ei,'SMA15'] and (df.loc[ei,'SMA15-5dif']< 0 ) 'down' else 'no' for ei in df.index]
```

I am lookig for something like this
Thanks for your time

[image: Example]

Comment: Could you provide a dummy df that resembles your data to work with?

Comment: you can use the df in the question by using yf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ei in df.index:
    if df.loc[ei,'Close'] > df.loc[ei,'SMA15'] and df.loc[ei,'SMA15-5dif'] > 0:
        df.at[ei,'Trend'] = 'up'
    elif df.loc[ei,'Close'] < df.loc[ei,'SMA15'] and df.loc[ei,'SMA15-5dif'] < 0:
        df.at[ei,'Trend'] = 'down'
    else:
        df.at[ei,'Trend'] = 'no'
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.select` takes advantage of vectorization:

```
condlist = [
    (df.loc[ei,'Close'] > df.loc[ei,'SMA15']) & (df.loc[ei,'SMA15-5dif'] > 0),
    (df.loc[ei,'Close'] < df.loc[ei,'SMA15']) & (df.loc[ei,'SMA15-5dif'] < 0)
]
choicelist = [
    'up',
    'down'
]

df.at[ei,'Trend'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, 'no')
```